# GCP - Vertex AI Model - Access GCS failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We have a Vertex AI model that was created using a custom image.
We are trying to access a bucket on startup but we are getting the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/...?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: {service account name} does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

The problem is that I can't find the service account that is mentioned in the error to give it the right access permissions..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving the endpoint the right service account

Comment: Currently facing the same problem. I've deployed the endpoint following [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/deploy-model-api#aiplatform_create_endpoint_sample-gcloud) piece of documentation. Which flag did you use to assign the service account to the endpoint? The page I've linked doesn't mention IAM at all. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same general issue. Vertex AI can't access my Cloud Storage bucket from a custom prediction container.

After digging through a complex tree of GCP Vertex docs, I found this:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/custom-service-account#setup

And

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#artifacts

**UPDATE**
After working through this, I was able to get GCS access to work.

1. Create a new service account and give it proper roles/permissions. You need your `PROJECT_ID` and `PROJECT_NUMBER`.

```bash
NEW_SA_EMAIL=new-service-account@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
AI_PLATFORM_SERVICE_AGENT=service-$PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-aiplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud iam service-accounts create $NEW_SA_NAME \
  --display-name="New Vertex AI Service Account" \
  --quiet

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
  --member="serviceAccount:$NEW_SA_EMAIL" \
  --role="roles/storage.admin" \
  --quiet

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin \
  --member=serviceAccount:$AI_PLATFORM_SERVICE_AGENT \
  --quiet \
  $NEW_SA_EMAIL
```

2. Upload your model and create the endpoint using the `gcloud` vertex ai commands...
3. Associate your new SA with the Vertex AI Endpoint when you deploy the model. You will need the `GCP_REGION`, `ENDPOINT_ID`, `MODEL_ID`, `DEPLOYED_MODEL_NAME`, and the `NEW_SA_EMAIL` from the first step.

```bash
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model $ENDPOINT_ID \
  --region=$GCP_REGION \
  --model=$MODEL_ID \
  --display-name=$DEPLOYED_MODEL_NAME \
  --machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
  --service-account=$NEW_SA_EMAIL
```